# Stuck on what is a simple query

Tags: sql, sql-server

If i have 2 tables one for people and one for holidays. Everytime someone goes on holiday the date gets entered in the holiday table. How would I query this so it shows the person name from the persons table if they have been on more then say 2 holidays between  1st of jan 2010 and the 6th of june 2010? This seems simple but I cant seem to do it.

Comment: a better solution is to just allow people to go on holiday as much as they want. if only my boss would implement that idea...

Comment: What have you come up with so far? Can you show the table structure (column names and types)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is the list of names of people taking 2 or more days between those two dates:

```
SELECT people.name
FROM people
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM days_taken
  WHERE people.person_id=days_taken.person_id AND
  days_taken.vacation_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
  HAVING count(*)>=2
)
```

If you want the name *and* the number of days:

```
SELECT people.name,count(*)
FROM people JOIN days_taken ON people.person_id=days_taken.person_id
WHERE days_taken.vacation_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
GROUP BY people.name
HAVING count(*)>=2
```

Comment: Thanks alot not tried the first one but the second answer works fine. i was stuck because I though you couldn't use the where clause with a aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT people.name, COUNT(*) c
FROM people INNER JOIN holidays
ON people.user_id = holidays.user_id
WHERE holidays.departure_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
GROUP BY people.name
HAVING c > 2
```

Comment: I don't think you can use the alias C in the Having clause. You need to write out HAVING Count(*) > 2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.name, p2.num_holidays
FROM people p1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT people.user_id, COUNT(*) as num_holidays
FROM people 
INNER JOIN holidays  ON (people.user_id = holidays.user_id)
WHERE holidays.departure_date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
GROUP BY people.user_id
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 2
)p2 ON (p2.user_id = p1.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2005 onwards, you can use the analytical function Count() OVER

```
select p.*, h.C
from person p inner join
(
    select distinct person_id, C = COUNT(*) over (partition by person_id)
    from holiday
    where holiday_date between '20100101' and '20100606'
) h on h.person_id = p.person_id and h.C >= 2
```